# Watch for multiple clicks on any buttons with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have several buttons on page:

```
<button id="button-event-status-4" data-closed="0" data-id="4" class="btn-danger">closed</button>
<button id="button-event-status-10" data-closed="1" data-id="10" class="btn-success">OPEN</button>
```

I need to pick a click at any of them (can be more than one at any moment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^='button-event-status-']").click(function() {
      alert ('it works');
    });
});
```

The code above not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Works fine here... https://jsfiddle.net/6ssskbgf/

Comment: actually, it works

Comment: is there a way to debug this somehow?

Comment: you are debugging it, somehow, but it is working. if you still want you can `console.log($("[id^='button-event-status-']"));` to see if a selector is returning something or it's empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give a same class to all button and bind click event to the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sameclass").click(function() {
      alert ('it works');
    });
});


<button id="button-event-status-4" data-closed="0" data-id="4" class="btn-danger sameclass">closed</button>
<button id="button-event-status-10" data-closed="1" data-id="10" class="btn-success sameclass">OPEN</button>
```

### Update

Since the buttons are added dynamically you need to bind click event on each button. Use this code to get it work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click",".sameclass",function() {
          alert ('it works');
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is my literal syntax now but it doesnt work. is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Can you please check in console what error are you getting?

Comment: The console is clear but somehow its not working at all.

Comment: I should have mentioned that these buttons are generated by another ajax success.

Comment: Check my updated answer it will surely work. :) @RWS

Comment: I have already deduced that :) Please update your answer again and note that it has to be new `$(document).ready()` selector and I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: Done. @RWS I have added text in my answer. :)